# How to get all <div>s in different <tr>s into one <tr> to print?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Here is a sample of my code and i want all s that include class="box" including their child divs go to only one  to be prepared for print

```
    <tr>         

    <div class="box3">        
    <div class="noprint">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="setPrint(this);"/>
        <div class="box3body">
               <h3 id="H1"></h3>
                    <div id="Div1"></div> 
                       <div id="Div2"></div>
                       <div id="Div3"></div>
 <div id="Div4"></div>
                       </div>
          </div>              
   </div>
    </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<div class="box3">
<div class="noprint">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="setPrint(this);"/>
        <div class="box3body">
               <h3 id="H3"></h3>
                    <div id="Div9"></div> 
                       <div id="Div10"></div>
                       <div id="Div11"></div>

</tr>
```

Comment: CSS can't alter your DOM structure. You could perhaps give the _appearance_ of the DIV's been within a single parent using CSS. Is this what you are actually asking?

Comment: You have errors in your html. Correct those first.

Comment: yea I solved it with a simple way, i blocked <td> in @media print